# Junk values on report for date

Tags: c#, reporting-services, crystal-reports

My "Transaction" table has a field called `FromDate` (DateTime). The database value under `FromDate` is saved as 25-Aug-2011 00:00:00.

After connecting my webservice to the report and dragging the `FromDate` field to the report, a garbage value such as `1 Jan-4713` gets displayed. The data is correct in the backend, only the preview is wrong. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is this SSRS or Crystal?

Comment: when you drag to the report what is the datatype that is getting for the field. Also when you right click on the field and in options what date time format is by default selected

Answer (score 0):

Dealt with something similar a little while back. Our symptom wasn't exactly the same, but I think the solution might be yours as well.

In crystal, create a formula:

`Date(Year({table.FromDate}), Month({table.FromDate}), Day({table.FromDate}))`

Then drag and drop that in as your column.

You can similarly do this for a DateTime:

`DateTime(Year(), Month(), Day(), Hour(), Minute(), Second())`

I've found that crystal disagrees with how our database stores dates/datetimes, but it can still handle them piece by piece if you define them. This can clear up lots of date related issues. One example would be if you are looking to show results within a timeframe.

This gave me errors:

`{?StartDate} >= {table.FromDate}`

But this didn't:

`{?StartDate} >= Date(Year({table.FromDate}), Month({table.FromDate}), Day({table.FromDate}))`

Hope this helps.